# is it possible to run unix commands with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run unix commands( like ls ) on linux server in mysql query
is it possible?

Comment: Yes. If you use `sys_exec` or `sys_eval`. See [here for a good example](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html)

Comment: Hi @enes-k G2ogle is a good start ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean the **mysql client**. In this case:

```
mysql> \! ls -l
```